# android sqlite getting data from database randomly

Tags: android, sqlite, random

my database contains questions and each question has three options. everything work fine but when I try to get the questions and options randomly it it gives me errors:

I found similar questions to my problem but it also didn't work,

here is my code:

```
public List<Test> getTest() {
List<Test> MyList = new ArrayList<Test>();

myDB=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + My_Table + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Test newQ = new Test();
newQ .setId(cursor.getInt(0));
newQ .setTest(cursor.getString(1));
newQ .setAns(cursor.getString(2));
newQ .setO1(cursor.getString(3));
newQ .setO2(cursor.getString(4));
newQ .setO3(cursor.getString(5));
MyList .add(newQ );
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
return MyList ;}
```

when I add this line to my code:

ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1

the activity will not work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote the `ORDER BY` part of the SQL as Java string literal as well:

```
"SELECT  * FROM " + My_Table + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I don't get this error from eclipse I get the error when I try to run the application in the emulator

Comment: Feel free to explain what "didn't work" means for you by editing the question.

Comment: In the edited question, you've forgotten a space between the table name and `ORDER`

Comment: my code works fine and I can get the data from sqlite database but when I add this code "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1" I get error from the emulator, I don't know why.

Comment: ... and if there's a "force close" error, include it in the question: Look for a red FATAL EXCEPTION in logcat and copy-paste the following stacktrace, including all the "caused by" exceptions.