# android show random data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have some data from the database that I want to show randomly and only 5 data appear, I've tried using ORDER BY RAND () but the app crashes when I open it

> below is my syntax query

```
public List<Soal> getSoal(){
    List<Soal> listSoal = new ArrayList<Soal>();
    String query = "select * from tbl_soal ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Soal s = new Soal();
            s.setSoal(cursor.getString(1));
            s.setPil_a(cursor.getString(2));
            s.setPil_b(cursor.getString(3));
            s.setPil_c(cursor.getString(4));
            s.setPil_d(cursor.getString(5));
            s.setJwban(cursor.getInt(6));
            s.setGambar(cursor.getInt(7));
            listSoal.add(s);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return listSoal;
}
```

> so where is the error, or is there any solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this answer as well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23628508/6672577

```
public List<Soal> getSoal() {
    List<Soal> listSoal = new ArrayList<Soal>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor != null) { // To check that cursor is not null.
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Soal s = new Soal();
                s.setSoal(cursor.getString(1));
                s.setPil_a(cursor.getString(2));
                s.setPil_b(cursor.getString(3));
                s.setPil_c(cursor.getString(4));
                s.setPil_d(cursor.getString(5));
                s.setJwban(cursor.getInt(6));
                s.setGambar(cursor.getInt(7));
                listSoal.add(s);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return listSoal;
}
```